# How to Call On an OnClick Button in Another Script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I'm trying to call on my "play" button from my main menu so that when i hit my play button it then plays my loading screen transition into the next scene. So far this is what my script looks like using the mousebuttondown instead of calling on my OnClick button as I'm not sure what to write in order to call on it so im using this for now.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Transition : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator transition;

    public float transitionTime = 4f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            LoadNextLevel();
        }
    }

    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadLevel(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1));
    }

    IEnumerator LoadLevel(int levelIndex)
    {
        transition.SetTrigger("Start");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(transitionTime);

        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelIndex);
    }
}
```

And heres the script im trying to reference from

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PlayGame ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }  

    public void QuitGame ()
    {
        Debug.Log("QUIT");
        Application.Quit();
    }
      
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: button.OnClick.Invoke()

Comment: So add the `LoadNextLevel` as a listener to the according `onClick` event ..? -> [Learn how to create UI Buttons](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/creating-ui-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `LoadNextLevel` function to your button from here :

[image]

You can also do it from script with something like this :

```
private void Start(){
  yourButtonGameObject.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
  {
     // Load your next scene
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok so i think this is pretty close but let me also show you the script that I’m mentioning it FROM so you could possibly write it out EXACTLY how i need it. I’m honestly a beginner although im about halfway thru the game im making, I still dont know the language that amazingly to where I can write my own script. Anyways here’s the script im mentioning from

Comment: I added the main script to my original post in case anyone else also needs it to write the exact line pf code i need. Thanks again!!

Comment: So If I understand it, you want to access the Transition class from MainMenu. If it's the case just add this line at top of your MainMenu class `public Transition transition;` then in the editor refrence it . and in the `PlayGame` function just call it e.g `transition.LoadNextLevel()`

Comment: Two things, in my Transition script i still have the “if” statement. What should i put there? or should i delete it? Also it says Coroutine could not be started because “transition” is not active!

Comment: Actually, it looks like you mentioned the scripts the wrong way. What I want is to play my Transition Prefab anytime i click “Play” from the main menu in game. so it will play my Transition Prefab and then play the next scene after i hit the “Play” button in the main menu. which is attached to the MainMenu class which uses “OnClick” for the “PlayGame()”. Some of that may not add up im just trying to give you all the info so you can put together the correct code, thank you again in advance!